# Как найти количество чисел?

Tags: python

```py
for i in range(300):
    s = i
    n = 1
    b = 0
    while s > n:
        s = s - 15
        n = n * 5
    if n == 125:
        print(i)
```

выводит кучу получившихся значений `i` (больше сотни).
Как узнать сколько всего получилось этих значений?

Comment: Опишите вашу задачу и какой ожидаемый результат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте переменную, куда будете аккумулировать все значения `i`. А в конце исполнения скрипта выведите длину получившегося списка

```py
res = []

for i in range(300):
    s = i
    n = 1
    b = 0
    while s > n:
        s = s - 15
        n = n * 5
    if n == 125:
        print(i)
        res.append(i)

print(f"{len(res)} значений")
```

Вывод

```
115 значений
```

Чтобы получить сумму всех членов списка используйте `sum`

```py
print(sum(res))

# out 
# 12995
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить сумму, вы можете создать переменную суммы и приплюсовывать туда i:

```
total = 0
for i in range(300):
    s = i
    n = 1
    b = 0
    while s > n:
        s = s - 15
        n = n * 5
    if n == 125:
        total += i
print(total)
```

Данный код выведет сумму нужных вам элементов.

Если необходимо количество, то также делаем переменную, но приплюсовывать к ней будем единицу (счётчик):

```
counter = 0
for i in range(300):
    s = i
    n = 1
    b = 0
    while s > n:
        s = s - 15
        n = n * 5
    if n == 125:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: Не называйте переменную `sum` - это встроенная функция питона

Comment: Благодарю за замечание, исправил на total.